# How to ship a shared library with one header file?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I want to create a shared library, based on several source files, each with a header file. Now, `header1.hpp` includes the line `#include "header2.hpp"`, which in turn includes the line `#include "header3.hpp"`, which in turn includes the line `#include "header4.hpp"`, and so on...

But I would like to ship my library with just a single header file. The only functions which my library needs to expose are those in `header1.hpp`. But it seems that I would also have to ship all these other header files along with it, which does not seem right. Typically when I am given a library, it comes with just one header...

Comment: that is certainly not the usual case - most libraries have more than 1 header.
You could amalgamate the headers though... meaning preprocessing them so they are all included into one monster header.

Comment: I usually try to avoid my headers from including any other header if possible.

Comment: Since the question did not specify that this library should be a header-only library, I don't understand where the problem is. Just compile `header2.hpp` and the other one in your library, then give your compiled library and `header1.hpp` to the user

Comment: But if I do that as you suggest @KABoissonneault, then when trying to link to the library, it tells me that `header2.hpp` does not exist -- because it is referenced in `header1.hpp`...

Comment: Use forward declarations and eliminate the include (of `header2.hpp` in `header1.hpp`)  if possible.

Comment: _"Typically when I am given a library, it comes with just one header..."_ Eh, really?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the C preprocessor to assemble all the includes into a single one:

1) create a dummy.c file that includes the required header files (just the toplevel ones). There may be a single one if you have one that directly or not includes all the other ones.

2) cc -E dummy.c > single_header.h

3) you will need to filter-out what comes from system includes in the generated header file. What comes from different headers is indicated by lines that start with a '#' sign. You can quite easily write a perl or awk or peek-your-favourite-small-language program that strips-out what you do not want, typically between a statement like

```
# xxx "/usr/include/something.h" yyy zzzz
```

and the next line that starts with a #

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expose a subset of all functions you can move the corresponding declarations to a new header `headerexp.hpp` and include this new header in `header1.hpp`.

Comment: And include the rest of the files in a detail sub directory or similar. That would make it seem like one header.